# Database design with recursion

Tags: database-design

I have table Person. One person can have many siblings from the same table. I have a hard time understanding on how to do this design, because If I do recursive relationship I can only add one sibling.

Table: PersonId, LastName,FirstName.

help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the sibling relationship is many to many, you need a second table called SIBLING, with two columns, the person id of each sibling in the relationship.

```
PERSON
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| PersonId | Last Name    | First Name   |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1        | Abc          | Def          |
| 2        | Ghi          | Def          |
| 3        | Jkl          | Stu          |
| 4        | Mno          | Def          |
| 5        | Pqr          | vwx          |
+----------+--------------+--------------+

SIBLING
+-----+-----+
| Id1 | Id2 |
+-----+-----+
| 1   | 2   |
| 1   | 4   |
| 2   | 4   |
| 3   | 5   |
+-----+-----+
```

Here SIBLING is sometimes called a "join table" or "association table."  Its PK is the whole table (a composite PK) and each column is a FK to PERSON.PersonId.

Comment: Okay. I got it. what about the relationship. is it going to be two relationships? from the same key? And does second table going to have compose PK out of two columns?